# UITableView - cells background color not working only in iOS 9.2?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have encountered a strange problem with one of my tableView's backgroundColors, it looks broken only in iOS 9.2?

I have tried to set the backgroundColor both via SB and via code:

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 22.0/255
                                                       green: 35.0/255
                                                        blue: 55.0/255
                                                       alpha: 1.0];

cell.accessoryView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 22.0/255
                                                         green: 35.0/255
                                                          blue: 55.0/255
                                                         alpha: 1.0];
```

[image]

Works fine though in iOS 10? Thoughts? I want to remove all the white-background stuff in the tableView to be specific...

Comment: Give it a try - "clearColor" contentView and cell background in Storyboard

Comment: Everything becomes white then in the cells. Even if I have the following backup aswell: 
    
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 22.0/255
                                                     green: 35.0/255
                                                      blue: 55.0/255
                                                     alpha: 1.0];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];// in table view cell

tableView.backgroundColor = "your color" // in view did load
```

**or**

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
cell.backgroundColor = "your color";
}
```

**or**

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor ="your color";
```

Comment: - (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
cell.backgroundColor = "your color";
} worked! Tricky problem. Cheers!

Comment: Cheers buddy :)